# lan extension over wide area

Tags: networking, lan, wan

When we use technology like leased line to extend a lan over a wide area(like when connecting two offices such that hosts in both offices use private ip addresses), why do we use encapsulations like PPP or HDLC.

Why can't we use the ethernet header to communicate because MAC addresses are unique and can easily be used to identify hosts just like a small area lan.

This question may seem a bit absurd but it has been bugging me. So please explain

Comment: If the leased line you have ordered is a layer 3 (ie routed) service, then you would need to encapsulate.  If you ordered a layer 2 service then you would not need to - it would literally serve as a lan extension.

Comment: @paul...ok...but that is what i asked...why should it be encapsulated using  different physical header...why not use the ethernet header